# 80 or 443 www to non-www 443

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, redirect

Followed all the guides in the Net, and my apache 2.4 configuration still doesn't work fully when using .htaccess.

Currently non-www 80 can redirect to non-www 443.

However, www won't redirect to non-www; it stays on www. Strange enough, it redirects from 80 to 443.

Here is my .htaccess, what have I done wrong?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https\:\/\/example\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript application/json
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]   # has custom code in index.php to handle _route and route

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: You need to change the order of rules. Keep in mind that the rules are processed from top to bottom. So make your redirections first, then internal rewrites.

Comment: OK, from top to bottom. Now I placed the 4 lines at the bottom to the top, and it still doesn't redirect to non-www 443. We can't get this portion to work for a long long time, and I really wonder if Apache 2.4.47 really work. In virtual host we got it to work, never in .htaccess.

Comment: If you can you certainly _always_ should prefer to place such rules into the actual host configuration. Tons of advantages.

Comment: We moved to shared hosting platform and no more self configuration. :-(

Comment: Your first redirection rule will redirect _both_ requested hosts, www and non-www to the non-www host. Actually _all_ requested host. So the second rule is obsolete.

Comment: Sure, using a shared platform you now lost tons of advantages :-)

Comment: You can also simplify the first rule to ``RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]``.

Comment: @arkascha I would thought it should work. But gosh it never works.

Comment: You should rather use 302 for testing, otherwise it is easy to get fooled by redirects that already got cached by the browser.

Comment: Have you tried doing both things in one go? Check if HTTPS was off, OR (needs the flag to be set, otherwise conditions are joined by an implicit AND) the host name was _not_ just `example.com` - then redirect to `https://example.com/ …`

Comment: @CBroe tried using [OR]. No good. :-( something seemingly so simple, but it doesn’t work.